# Use Ajax to render a html table

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to know how to realize following project

Actually I have a php code which renders a table

```
<table id = "oldata" class ="table table-bordered">

    <thead>
            <tr class ="success">
                    <th class="text-center">Stage</th>
                    <th class="text-center">REQUEST</th>
                    <th class="text-center">REPLY</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    <tbody>
<?php

    foreach($allinfool as $infool){
        print("<tr>");
        print("<td>{$infool["Stage"]}</td>");
        print("<td class='text-left'>" .nl2br($infool["comment"])."</td>");
        print("<td class='text-left'>" .nl2br($infool["resultcom"]). "</td>");
        print("</tr>");
    }

?>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

So far so good, however I want to build many tables like above based on action from user. 
I mean he will have a list of items (like choice 1, choice 2, choice 3...) and then by clicking this it will render without reloading the page above html (based on new allinfool array).

My point is I want to do it via Ajax. So far I could manage Ajax but not to render above content of html.
I could manage to render back one number or one text but in this case it is more complicated since html is mixed with php.
Could you please help me to figure out how to realize this Ajax technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your code in file like `table.php` then from the `index.php` use Jquery to call it and render the table:

HTML:

```
<button id="rendertable">Render new table</button>
<div id="render"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#rendertable').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "table.php",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#render').append(response);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Everytime you will click the button it will render a new table appended to `render` element

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Should I do anything special inside table.php to spit out hmtl? Could you please show me?

Comment: No you don't need anything (to render the table as is), if you call table.php from a browser you will see what you will render: the table.

Comment: I tried it, and that's exactly what I expected for. Thanks –

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to do this code in you main file from where you want to call table.php file - 
and pass the array variable into your $allinfool variable in table.php like-
$allinfool = array();
$allinfool = $_POST['variable_value'];
You have done.

//this code is for your index.php file or any other file from where you want to call table.php
 <?php 
    $arr = array(
        array("Stage" => "Stage_value1", "comment" => "comment_value1", "resultcom" => "resultcom_value1"),
        array("Stage" => "Stage_value2", "comment" => "comment_value2", "resultcom" => "resultcom_value2"),
        array("Stage" => "Stage_value3", "comment" => "comment_value3", "resultcom" => "resultcom_value3")
    );
    $arr = json_encode($arr);
    ?>
    <button id="button">Click Me</button>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
      $("button#button").on("click", function(){
        $( "#success" ).load( "table.php", { 'variable_value' : <?php echo $arr ?> }, function( response, status, xhr ) {
          if ( status == "error" ) {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
          }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```