# jquery to parse ajax response based on id then append

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am wondering if its possible to parse an ajax response and based on the id of the html element append it.

For example:

Here is a sample response response data I am getting:

```
<div id="message">
  <p class="text-danger">Please enter your message</p>
</div>
<div id="antispam">
  <p class="text-danger">Your anti-spam is incorrect </p>
</div>
```

Note that there is two divs in the response data **id="message** & **id="antispam"**

I would like to write the response to two different places on the html page.

**For the id equals message**

I would like to write it to:
   $('#msg').html(response);

**For the id equals antispam**

I would like to write it to: 
   $('#spam').html(response);

My current code writes the whole response into the same html element but as per the above i would like to split it. How can i alter the below code to achieve the above?

```
success: function (response) {
  $('#Response').html(response);
},
```

Comment: do you already have some #message and #antispam elements? if so, you have to change it - id's need to be unique. if you include the response into those elements, the id's are not unique anymore. second question - may you alter your ajax response format or is this not possible?

Comment: good point - i can change the element id easily to make things unique. I can alter whatever needs altering if its going to help. Do you have a sample code you like me to try ?

Comment: i updated my post to make the elment id's unique #msg and #spam

Comment: with n01ze solution, id changes are obsolete, since you only insert the text into the existing div. you loose the <p> element though and may need to wrap it around again...

Comment: I got similar issue, you can refer to attached link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273948/use-ajax-to-render-a-html-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this filtering,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        var html = '<div id="message"><p class="text-danger">Please enter yourmessage</p></div><div id="antispam"><p class="text-danger">Your anti-spam is incorrect </p></div>'

        alert('The value filtered out from div#message ' + $(html).filter('#message').find('.text-danger').text());

        alert('The value filtered out from div#antispam ' + $(html).filter('#antispam').find('.text-danger').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thx for the solution. any idea why this doesnt work **var html = response** i would like to avoid manually typing out the html data

Comment: Check properly , put response in console.log(response) and share . I  should work definately

Comment: when i run your solution using var html = respose - i get this in the popup window "The value filtered out from div#message"

Comment: hold on one of my div id's has a typo - i will correct and try again

Comment: Yes definately , now you have to modify your code according to your need.Instead of alert put in HTML of some div etc :)

Comment: Seems like @n01ze has already answered in similar way as I did. All I put this as per his requirement

Comment: As you mentioned earlier. Only the text is extracted and the <p> is dropped. how can I add it or wrap it back in?

Comment: @user3436467  --->>> "$(html).filter('#message').html() ", just remove find() and text() to html

Comment: @n01ze - Works perfectly. I am all set - thx for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using filtering the HTML response like below and passing it to relevant id's inside **success** callback. Try below code

```
success: function (response) {
  var resHtml = '<div id="message"><p class="text-danger">Please enter your message</p></div><div id="antispam">  <p class="text-danger">Your anti-spam is incorrect </p></div>';
   $('#msg').html($(resHtml).filter('#message').find('.text-danger').text());

   $('#spam').html($(resHtml).filter('#antispam').find('.text-danger').text());
},
```

Comment: @Anand - thx for completing n01ze's solution i will give it a go

Comment: it works very well but i noticed only the text is extracted and the <p> is dropped. how can I add it or wrap it back in?

Comment: Do you want <p class="text-danger">Please enter your message</p> as  a part of #msg